# Uniqueness of a map.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{C}^*$ be a homomorphism. Where $(\mathbb{Z}^n,+)$ is considered as an additive group and $(\mathbb{C}^*$ is considered as an multiplicative group. Fix $b_1,\ldots, b_n \in \mathbb{C}$. We define $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = a_1^{b_1}\cdots a_n^{b_n}$. Then $f$ is a homomorphism. Is this map $f$ unique? Are there some other map $f': \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{C}^*$ involves $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ which is also a homomorphism? Thank you very much.

Comment: For this to be a homomorphism I think you want 
$$f(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=b_1^{a_1}\cdots b_n^{a_n}.$$
But I don't quite understand what you are asking. Any choice of non-zero elements $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$ gives a homomorphism. So there is nothing unique about this, so you are interested in something else. What do you mean by *...involves $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ which is also a homomorphism?*

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a homomorphism. Did you mean $f(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = b_1^{a_1}\cdots b_n^{a_n}$?

Comment: Like would you be happy with the homomorphism
$$f(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=b_2^{a_1}b_1^{a_2}b_3^{a_3}\cdots b_n^{a_n},$$ where the roles of $b_1$ and $b_2$ (or, if you prefer, the roles of $a_1$ and $a_2$) are simply interchanged?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ is fixed.

Comment: Ok, so think of that suggestion in the alternate form that the roles of $a_1$ and $a_2$ are swapped. To reiterate: what do you require from $f'$ for you to say that "$b_1,\ldots,b_n$ are involved"? Would $f(a_1,a_2)=b_1^{2a_1-a_2}b_2^{a_1+a_2}$ match with what you have in mind? (in the case $n=2$)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you very much.